# Python VS Code auto import path includes src

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have a folder structure like this:

```
workspaceFolder
  subproject1
    src
      subproject1

  subjproject2
    src
      subproject2

  etc..
```

When I am missing an import it suggests a path for autoimport but it always looks like this: `from subproject1.src.subproject1.bla import bla` whereas I'd like it to look like `from subproject1.bla import bla`.

It seems to find files correctly if you manually type in the imports and indexes them and all.

I have PYTHONPATH set in .env file. The PYTHONPATH looks like `"workspaceFolder\subproject1\src\;workspaceFolder\subproject1\src\"`.

I have the following potentially relevant entries in settings.json

```
"python.analysis.autoSearchPaths": true,
"python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
```

Comment: Are you interested in modifying your project so that Python natively understands how to find each `subproject*` without the `PYTHONPATH` shenanigans, or are you just looking to make VS Code work better with the `PYTHONPATH` shenanigans?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to keep my folder structure as it is. Happy to make other modifications. But if modifying the folder structure is the only way to fix this then that is also an acceptable answer (it is what it is).

Comment: You should be able to keep the folder structure as-is. Are you currently using any Python build system / do you have a [`pyproject.toml`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0518/) file?

Comment: I don't use a build system locally. There is a build system but I don't directly interact with it.

Comment: Adding a local build system is a pretty simple and non-invasive process. It should just mean adding a `pyproject.toml` file with ~10 lines of boilerplate text. In essence, all  a Python build system does is tell frontends like pip how to map a source tree to Python packages. There's a few standard one's to choose, but which you choose likely won't matter unless you want to use it for other purposes (e.g. environment isolation, dependency management). If you pick any, and then run `pip install -e .` from the root directory of your project, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) as your build-backend, you can the following to your `pyproject.toml` file to make your `subproject*` packages automatically discoverable:

```
packages = [
    { from = "subproject1/src", include = "subproject1" },
    { from = "subproject2/src", include = "subproject2" },
    # ...
]
```

After configuring your `pyproject.toml` file, simply run `pip install -e .` from the root directory of your project (or `poetry install` if you're using poetry more generally).

Each `subproject*/src` directory will then be placed on the import path of your current interpreter (assuming the default editable install). Any and all tools that search the current interpreter's import path will also be able to discover them (including VS Code, as well as static analysis tools like mypy, etc.).

Note that if you're only using Poetry as a PEP-517 build backend, you *do not* have to [install the full tool](https://python-poetry.org/docs/) per the steps in the documentation. Merely including

```
[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

in your `pyproject.toml` is enough. Each time you build your project, `poetry-core` will be installed into an isolated temporary virtual environment.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I tried this, I placed pyproject.toml at the top level (under workspaceFolder). It looks like this:

```[tool.poetry]
packages = [
    { from = "subproject1/src", include = "subproject1" },
    { from = "subproject2/src", include = "subproject2" },
    # ...
]```

But I still get subproject1.src.subproject1 in autoimport.

Comment: @SMeznaric Added a clarifying add. You'll need to flesh out `pyproject.toml` a bit more and then run `pip install -e .`. You can check the [poetry docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/) for what a minimal `pyproject.toml` file looks like, or keep running `pip install -e .` and fix whatever the error message tells you to until it works.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have tried to set this up but seemingly unsuccessfully. The poetry file seems OK now, it writes the lock file, then I get permission denied. Same with `pip install -e .`.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to use the system interpreter? If so, try using a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for your project. [Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Comment: Managed to run it! Looks like doing --no-root --no-directory seems to do the trick. However, unfortunately that has seemingly not affected the auto import functionality. Tried to restart VS Code also no change.

Comment: Looks like I have a conda environment set up as well.

Comment: Make sure that the interpreter you `pip install`'d to is the same as the one VS Code thinks you're using. You may also want to set `autoSearchPaths` to `false`, and potentially relax/remove other settings that affect how VS code is guessing the available package names. After setting up the `pyproject.toml` file, your packages are available in the exact same way that any 3rd party packages are, so if VS code is using the right interpreter, it should be able to provide completions for the them the same as it would for any 3rd party dependency.

Comment: You may also have luck with using `python.analysis.{include,exclude}` in `settings.json` to prevent VS Code from assuming that `workspaceFolder` is on the import path when it really ought not.

Comment: Interesting point. Looks like the interpreter indeed wasn't the same. However that hasn't solved the issue. It seems that indeed the problem is that the workspaceFolder is included in the search path for some reason. (Based on Output window at the bottom from the python language server). I have tried to use exclude it explicitly but it seems that also doesn't do anything... I just have no idea where it gets the idea from to include the root directory.

Comment: Suddenly started working! I am not sure why, but I tried to load my environment did another poetry install then reloaded the language server and voila! Thank you very much sir!